# Cast generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I get an object back from a method. The object is of type object and I can't change this because of backwards compatibility. If it is of a certain type (`Response<T>` bellow) then I need to access the property `Payload` which is of type `T` so that I can serialize it as part of a another object and send it off. The problem is that since I don't know the type of `T` I can't cast the object to `Response<T>` to access `Payload` even though I don't care about its type.

Here is my object with the generic type:

```
public class Response
{
   public int Status { get; set; }
   public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class Response<T> : Response
{
   public T Payload { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I would like to do:

```
// Will sometimes be of type Response<T>
object data = LegacyCode();
if (data.GetType().IsGenericType && data.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Response<>)) {
   var payload = ((Response<object>)data).Payload; // Unable to cast object of type...
}
```

But the only way I could find to do this is by using dynamics.

```
// Will sometimes be of type Response<T>
object data = LegacyCode();
if (data.GetType().IsGenericType && data.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Response<>)) {
   var payload = ((dynamice)data).Payload;     
}
```

Don't ask why things are the way they are (I'm wondering that myself). I have to do code gymnastics to keep backwards compatibility in this system. **I just want compile time checking on the name of the property.**

Here is a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dXxHbD

**UPDATE:**

I need to be able to serialize and deserialize this object. Originally `Response` had a property `Payload` of type `object`. This caused serialization issues when `Response<T>` was deserialized because the `Payload` property was of type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` which could not be cast to `T`. Here is an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uc15HD

The problem was that I was going the wrong direction and the deserialization works if I cast `T` to `object` rather than try to cast `object` to `T`. When I store the value as its specific type `T` then the serializer knows what to deserialize the string to.
Here is an example using Jon's answer below: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KwudAx

Here is a similar example using Matias' solution of using covariance: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kCjZr4

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do... is `data` meant to be a `Type` rather than an instance of the type? That's what it looks like from what you're calling, but then you're trying to cast it to `Response<T>`...

Comment: And can you change `Response<T>` at all, e.g. to have a non-generic abstract base type?

Comment: Sorry. Data is an instance of a type. It will sometimes be of type Response<T>. I can't really change that it is "sometimes" that. But I need to special handle it when it is.

Comment: I used to have the non-generic base class but I had serialization issues on the client where the non-generic Payload property could not be unboxed to its generic type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get compile-time checking of the name of the property, you can keep the dynamic typing, but get the runtime "mini-compiler" to do the hard work:

```
object data = LegacyCode();
object payload = GetPayload(data);
// Use payload

...

private static object GetPayload<T>(Response<T> response)
{
    return response.Payload;
}

public static object GetPayload(object data)
{
    // Fallback method. You could return null here and use
    // that to indicate in the calling code that it wasn't a
    // Response<T>...
}
```

A much better solution would be to add an non-generic interface or an extra base class though. For example:

```
public class Response
{
   public int Status { get; set; }
   public string Message { get; set; }
}

public interface IPayloadHolder
{
    public object Payload { get; }
}

public class Response<T> : Response, IPayloadHolder
{
   public T Payload { get; set; }

   // By using explicit interface implementation, this
   // doesn't get in the way for normal usage.
   IPayloadHolder.Payload { get { return Payload; } }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
var payloadHolder = data as IPayloadHolder;
if (payloadHolder != null)
{
    var payload = payloadHolder.Payload;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My issue with serialization was that I was going the wrong direction. I held the payload in a property on Response of type object and referenced it from Response<T> rather than holding the payload in a property of type T and having a property to cast it to an object. I will add links to code examples in my question to illustrate this.

Comment: I just had to use this solution since enums don't support covariance like the other solution requires.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that you need to use [*covariance*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx).

Design an interface `IResponse<out T>`:

```
public interface IResponse<out T>
{
   public T Payload { get; }
}
```

And implement it on `Response<T>`. Now you can cast it to `IResponse<object>`:

```
Response<string> x = new Response<string>();
IResponse<object> y = x; // implicit cast
```

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could mark both your's and Jon's answers as the answers. I will add an example using your solution.

Comment: @bygrace No problem. Answers are here to provide more approaches to solve the same issue. It will be useful for future visitors (and even you!)